# Scripts not running when using get function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the `$.get()` function to extract some data from my site. Everything works great however on one of the pages the information I need to extract is dynamically created and then inserted into a `<div>` tag.

So in the `<script>` tag, a function is run and then the data is inserted into `<div id="infoContainer"></div>`. I need to get the information from `#infoContainer`, however when I try to do so in the `$.get()` function, it just says it's empty. I have figured out that it is because the `<script>` tag is not being run. Is there another way to do this?

Edit:I am making a PhoneGap application for my site using jQuery to move content around so it's more streamlined for mobiles.

This is the code on my page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var embedTag = document.createElement("embed");
    var infoContainer = document.getElementById("infoContainer");

    if (infoContainer != null) {
        embedTag.setAttribute("height", "139");
        embedTag.setAttribute("width", "356");...other attributes

        infoContainer.appendChild(embedTag);
    });
});
```

As you can see, it puts content into the `#infoContainer` tag. However, when I try to extract info from that tag through the get function it shows it as empty.I have done the same to extract headings and it works great. All I can gather is the script tag is not firing.

Comment: What are you doing exactly? Can we see a little code?

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with your code without seeing the code that has the problem.

Comment: `$.get()` just puts the returned data in a string, it doesn't execute it. Even if you tell it it's HTML, it has no idea what you plan on doing with it. Maybe you really need `$.load`

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you the contents of the element:

```
$('#infoContainer').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your script is executing before the DOM is loaded.

So if you are manipulating DOM elements you should wait till DOM is loaded to manipulate it. Alternately you can place your script tag at the end of your HTML document.

```
// These three are equivalent, choose one:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initializeOrWhatever);
$( initializeOrWhatever );
$.ready( initializeOrWhatever );

function initializeOrWhatever(){
  // By the time this is called, the DOM is loaded and you can read/write to it
  $.getJSON('/foo/', { myData: $('#myInput').val() }, onResponse);
  function onResponse(res){  
    $(document).html('<h1>Hello '+res+'</h1>');
  };
};
```

Otherwise... post more specifics and code

Answer (score 0):

You have no ID to reference. Try setting one before you append

```
embedTag.setAttribute("id", "uniqueID");
```

Comment: sorry I didn't show that in the post but i do have an ID reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are wanting to use jQuery, but your example code has vanilla JavaScript. Your entire function can be simplified using the following jQuery ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/whrr9/4/)):

```
(function () {
    var embedTag = $(document.createElement("embed"));
    var infoContainer = $("#infoContainer");

    if (infoContainer.length) {
        embedTag.attr({"height": 139, "width": 356});
        infoContainer.append(embedTag);
    }

    console.log(infoContainer.html()); // This gets you the contents of #infoContainer
})();
```

[jQuery's .get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method is for sending `GET` requests to a server-side script. I don't think it does what you are wanting to do.

Comment: hey chris if I have on a page                                              <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Id = "586410650001";
  .....
        );
    });
</script>                                                                  Is there a way to get the ID from another page?